# Save/Load MXNet model parameters using NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, mxnet

How can I save the parameters for an MXNet model into a NumPy file (.npy)? After doing so, how can I load these parameters from the .npy file back into my model?

Here is a minimal example to save the parameters for MXNet model using MXNet API.

```
import mxnet as mx
from mxnet import gluon
from mxnet.gluon.model_zoo import vision
import numpy as np

num_gpus = 0
ctx = [mx.gpu(i) for i in range(num_gpus)] if num_gpus > 0 else [mx.cpu()]
resnet = vision.resnet50_v2(pretrained=True, ctx=ctx)

parameters = resnet.collect_params()
resnet.save_parameters('model.params')
```

Minimal example to load parameters back into the model from a file using MXNet API.

```
import mxnet as mx
from mxnet import gluon
from mxnet.gluon.model_zoo import vision
import numpy as np

num_gpus = 0
ctx = [mx.gpu(i) for i in range(num_gpus)] if num_gpus > 0 else [mx.cpu()]
resnet = vision.resnet50_v2(pretrained=True, ctx=ctx)

resnet.load_parameters('model.params', ctx=ctx)
```

In both the above examples, I'm using MXNet API to save/load model parameters. Instead of this, I want to save/load the model using numpy and then use these parameters into my MXNet model. How can I do that?